# HttpClient GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync() Method hanging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services

In ASP.NET Project I using web service that I get data from it by APIs,
I am using this code to connect with web service but it hanging:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var result = ICDa.GetCodeResult().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        return View();
    }

    private  async Task<string> GetCodeResult()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var disco = await 
 client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://icdaccessmanagement.who.int");
       if (disco.IsError)
       {
          return "error";
       }
       else
       {
           return "success";
       }
    }
}
```

But when I using this code in Console App, it work right, no problem

Comment: It is the first part of code and the problem is that when run code and when reach to this line client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync, it is hanging, So the rest of code is not important

Comment: It absolutely is important. You may be experiencing a deadlock, but it's hard for us to tell since you haven't provided a [mcve]. We certainly can't rule it out without one. So, please provide it.

Comment: I updated the post, the code is run in console app with no problem

Comment: You still have not shown how this code is called. As I told you before, that's important. You're the one coming here asking for help - I suggest you humor us. It's going to help prive or rule out a common scenario that describes your situation. What have you got to lose by providing it?

Comment: If you don't know which piece of code has a problem, it is recommended to share all the nearby codes, and pay attention to hiding confidential information. It is suggested to re-create a new post, which seems to be related to deadlock or thread. Has nothing to do with the current GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync() Method.

Comment: I updated the post, I think it clear now all the code, sorry

Comment: As I suspected, you're calling this async code incorrectly. Instead of .GetAwaiter().GetResult(), you need to await the call to GetCodeResult, like `await ICDa.GetCodeResult()`. That means your action method needs to be marked as async and return a Task<ActionResult> instead of ActionResult. If you find yourself using .GetAwaiter().GetResult() or .Result or .Wait() you likely aren't calling async code properly and are at risk of deadlock.

Comment: This goes to show the importance of providing a [mcve] up front instead of withholding it.

Comment: I had the same issue. My code is slightly different than shown here;.I have an extra inner async method that is called with an ".Result". It works fine in a netcore 3.1 console app but hangs in a (in my case) netstandard 2.1 Xamarin app. I solved it by removing the ".Result" from the inner method in case of the Xamarin app. I can't really explain what caused the difference in behaviour between both execution environments.

Answer (score 0):

**Mason's comment is correct. I try to run in console application and webapi application, all work fine.**

*So my test results proved that GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync() in HttpClient is normal.*

*Test Code in Console Application*

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using IdentityModel.Client;

using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ClientCredentialsConsoleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await aa();
            }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        public static async Task<string> aa()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://icdaccessmanagement.who.int");
            if (disco.IsError)
            {
                return "error";
            }
            else {
                return "success";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*And Result*

[image]

*Test Code in Webapi Application*

```
[HttpGet("Test_HttpClient")]
public async Task<string> Test_HttpClient()
{
    string res=await aa();
    return res;
}
private  async Task<string> aa()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://icdaccessmanagement.who.int");
    if (disco.IsError)
    {
        return "error";
    }
    else
    {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

*And Result*

[image]

Comment: Assume you're in a modern version of .NET, you can do an async main method. And if not, you can do async void, as the main method of a console app is one of the few places that's okay to do.